# Tried scraping group on for practice only. Why it returns less results?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, urllib3

I am new to Python scraping, so as part of the practice I was trying few other sites where often data wasn't returned at all, but when I checked Groupon, I found that `urllib` only returns the first 8 results, while there are 36 results on the browser page.

I am using `urllib` and `BS4`. below is the code

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
req = Request('https://www.groupon.com/browse/chicago?category=beauty-and-spas')
req.add_header('User-Agent',
               'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.121 Safari/537.36')
try:
    with urlopen(req) as response:
        htmlcontent = response.read().decode('utf-8')
except:
    htmlcontent = None
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlcontent, 'lxml')
all_links = soup.find('div', { 'id': 'pull-results' }).select('figure > div > a')
```

Can somebody please tell, what am I missing in the code to be able to extract all the data?
If this doesn't work or shouldn't work, then do we have selenium as the only option?

Comment: Please do not post images as code. Instead, edit your question with the code you have tried and provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I'm going to guess this is a javascript issue.  urllib can't do javascript.

Comment: @JohnGordon Well, this time the data is actually in the HTML.

Comment: I have tried using lxml and html.parser in Soup. but no difference.
@JohnGordon : I have no idea how to invoke javascript  following a urllib request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following to get all the items and their links traversing next pages:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

base_link = 'https://www.groupon.com/browse/chicago?category=beauty-and-spas'
url = 'https://www.groupon.com/partial/browse/get-paginated-cards?'

params = {
    'category': 'beauty-and-spas',
    'page': 1
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers['user-agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36'
    r = s.get(base_link)
    params['_csrf'] = r.cookies['_csrf']

    while True:
        print("current page----------->",params['page'])
        res = s.get(url,params=params)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(res.json()[0]['cardSlotHtml'],"lxml")
        if not soup.select_one("figure[data-pingdom-info='purchasable-deal']"):break
        for item in soup.select("figure[data-pingdom-info='purchasable-deal']"):
            item_title = item.select_one(".cui-udc-details .cui-udc-title").get_text(strip=True)
            item_link = item.select_one(".cui-content > a[href]").get("href")
            print(item_title,item_link)

        params['page']+=1
```

Answer (score 0):

The other 28 links are loaded dynamically, therefore `urllib` doesn't support it. However, you can scrape them by sending a `GET` request to:

`https://www.groupon.com/partial/browse/get-lazy-loaded-cards?category=beauty-and-spas&_csrf=P6rFPl1o-xDta8uOABKo_9LOiUajyK9bieMg`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen


req = Request(
    "https://www.groupon.com/partial/browse/get-lazy-loaded-cards?category=beauty-and-spas&_csrf=P6rFPl1o-xDta8uOABKo_9LOiUajyK9bieMg"
)
req.add_header(
    "User-Agent",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.121 Safari/537.36",
)

with urlopen(req) as response:
    htmlcontent = response.read().decode("utf-8")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlcontent, "lxml")

    for tag in soup.find_all(class_=r'\"cui-content\"'):
        try:
            link = tag.find("a")["href"]
        except TypeError:
            continue
        print(link.replace('\\"', "").replace("\\n", ""))
```

Output:

```
https://www.groupon.com/deals/yupo-health-2?deal_option=75076cab-9268-4c2d-9459-e79a559dfed6
https://www.groupon.com/deals/infinity-laser-spa-2-4?deal_option=4dc14f7d-29ac-45e1-a664-ea76ddc44718
https://www.groupon.com/deals/dr-laser-nyc-3?deal_option=232325a0-8b3f-4fa9-b42b-7dc668ff7474
...
...
```

Comment: Thanks. This is nice but how did you find out the url https://www.groupon.com/partial/browse/get-lazy-loaded-cards?category=beauty-and-spas&_csrf=P6rFPl1o-xDta8uOABKo_9LOiUajyK9bieMg . And it shows 28 results better than what had written. And how to navigate to next pages as Beauty and Spas has 17 paginations

Comment: Okay got it. I found that in Network calls. but each time the csrf value is difference. Also found that csrf value can be any thing. I modified the csrf value in your code and it still worked, which is strange :)

Comment: Thanks @MedelG, you are great